# Heap Corruption Detected after normal block (#164)

Tags: c++

Lately, I've been trying to understand the basics of dynamic programming and now I am facing some issues with Heap Corruption. My code breaks when I try to free the memory. 
I have done some research on the internet and I found out the I receive this message because I write in some unallocated memory space. However I still don't know where the mistake is , or how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
std::ifstream f("file.in");
void read(int *a, int &n)
{
    f >> n;///scanf("%d", &n);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        f >> a[i];/// scanf_s("%d", &a[i]);
}
int main()
{
    int *a, *b, *c;
    int na = 0, nb = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, kk = 1, p;
    a = (int*)malloc(na*sizeof(int));
    b = (int*)malloc(nb*sizeof(int));
    c = (int*)malloc(kk * sizeof(int));
    read(a, na);
    read(b, nb);
    while (i < na && j < nb)
    {
        if (a[i] < b[j])
        {
            kk++;
            c = (int*)realloc(c, kk * sizeof(int));
            c[k] = a[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            kk++;
            c = (int*)realloc(c, kk * sizeof(int));
            c[k] = b[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    if (i < na)
        for (p = i; p < na; p++)
        {
            kk++;
            c = (int*)realloc(c, kk*sizeof(int));
            c[k++] = a[p];
        }
    if (j < nb)
        for (p = j; p < nb; p++)
        {
            kk++;
            c = (int*)realloc(c, kk *sizeof(int));
            c[k++] = b[p];
        }

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
        printf("%d ", c[i]);
    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: **na** and **nb** are null (equals 0), so you do not allocate memory when you do `malloc(na * sizeof(int))`, same for **b** allocation using **nb**.

Comment: I am a student learning C after previously learning some C++ and now I use both of them when I code. Sorry if it bothered you.

Comment: Your memory allocation is a mess - you should really use proper C++ containers, not C-style malloc etc. Anyway, both `a` and `b` start off with size 0 and yet you try and store elements in them in the first two calls to `read` - from then on your heap is corrupt and all bets are off...

Comment: Just don't. Code in C or code in C++ but try to avoid mixing both

Answer (score 1):

```
int na = 0;
int *a = (int*)malloc(na*sizeof(int));
read(a, na);
```

Here's the problem. You create a buffer of size 0, and then you write "in" it. Must create the buffer only when you figure out the size, which is after reading the size. Rearrange the code so that this line makes sense:

```
int na = 0;
int *a = read(na);
```

Or better yet:

```
std::vector<int> a = read();
```